# For a male what is the probability that he is actually HIV positive if his blood test shows positive

Tags: probability

Suppose that in Malawi the probability that a male is HIV positive is $0.15$ and the probability that a female is HIV positive is $0.2$. Also suppose $51\%$ of the population is female and that a blood test shows negative for $2\%$ of the people who are HIV positive and shows positive for $0.5\%$ of people who are HIV negative.

1. For a male what is the probability that he is actually HIV positive if his blood test shows positive.
2. if the blood sample tests positive, what is the probability came from a woman.

I have an idea, this is bayes theorem. 
let $M$= Male, $F$=Female, $H^+$= HIV positive, $H^-$= HIV negative, $T^+$= Test positive and $T^-$= Test negative. then $P(M)=0.49, P(F)=0.51, P(H^+/M)=0.15, P(H^-/M)=0.85, P(H^+/F)=0.2, P(H^-/F)=0.80, P(T^+/H^+)=0.98, P(T^-/H^+)=0.02, P(T^+/H^-)=0.005$ and $P(T^-/H^+)=0.995$. But the problem is on how to evaluate the probabilities required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As it stands you don't have enough information. Without additional assumptions, it is possible that either or both of the false reporting cases are correlated to gender.  You can exclude that by assuming independence, but I have no idea if that is a physically realistic assumption or not.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: No one is helping me here? I have added some of the preliminary information here.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: 
  Assume that the men being tested are a representative
  sample of the men in Malawi. That's a shaky assumption since positive
  men might be more or less likely to tested, but that's all you knnow to
  begin with.

15% are HIV+ and 98% of them test +, giving

```
 (.15)*(.98) or 14.7% true positive.
```

85% of the men are HIV- but .5% of them test +, giving

```
 (.85)*(.005) or 0.425% false positive
```

And:

```
 (.85)*(.995) or 84.575% true negative

 (.15)*(.02) or 0.3% false negative
```

For the purpose of the question only the positive test results count, so

```
  (14.7)/(14.7+.425) or 97.19% of all positives are true positives.
```

Question 2:
  This question should never arise, unless a number of unmarked samples
  are being tested for some strange reason. The approach is the same
  with one additional probability to consider. That jumps the number of
  categories to eight, from the four where only men were considered.
  Only four of the categories matter for the question: true positive
  women, false positive women, true positive men, and false positive
  men.

Doing just one of them, for an example: true positive women:

```
  (.51)*(.2)*(.98) or 9.996%
```

The answer to the question is the ratio of all positive women (true
  and false) to all positives (true/false/male/female).

Using Bayes' Theorem is the right approach if you're familiar
with it. In my answers I used a tree approach which you might find
easier to use.